# How to simply serve a bundled PDF?

Tags: node-webkit

I've a really simply html file with only a simple link

```
<a href="output.pdf">Get the file</a>
```

I want, for example on Windows, user can see the pdf in Adobe Reader as if downloaded and opened from browser.

But when I launch `nw.exe C:\Node-WebKit-Project` and click on the link, on the console I see this:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/pdf: "file:///C:/Node-WebKit-Project/output.pdf".

How to allow opening of pdf ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e.g create a link in your app.
Set a on click event handler on this link.
Set a data attribute with the URL of the pdf file.
Then use [gui.Shell.openExternal()](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Shell) method to open the pdf with the system default application.

html code:

```
...
<a id="pdfLink" data-href="file://file.pdf"></a>
...
```

javascript code:

```
...
$('#pdfLink').on('click', function () {
  gui.Shell.openExternal($(this).data('href'));
});
...
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing issues with making this work with Mac. I'm getting 

    [17540:0106/113829:WARNING:platform_util_mac.mm(127)] NSWorkspace failed to open URL

Can you please help?

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to open? You can check on the cpmmand line with the open tool e.g. open <URL> and see if your system can open it.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer is to make sure that you have the following in your `package.json` file

```
"webkit": {
  "plugin": true
}
```

source: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Third-party-browser-plugins

However, you then have to make sure that either the PDF viewer plugin is pre-installed on the system, or bundled with the app. I've not tested any of this.

Comment: This is not what I want, I need user can see the pdf in the default pdf viewver. I said "I want, for example on Windows, user can see the pdf in Adobe Reader" .. or xviewer on ubuntu, for another example. Proably i'll resolve using shell ... but I'm not able to try now. But thanks for reply me !

Comment: @Michal Charemza - any idea where to get the PDF viewer plugin?